# Has anybody had any success with a college level "flipped classroom?"

Tags: teaching, professorship, writing-style

The "flipped classroom" seems quite successful and growing in popularity in high school. Students get their lectures at home from youtube or kahnacademy, write clarifying questions about the material and then bring it to class. This allows the instructor to focus on practice and application. Does anybody have any information about its success or failure when implemented at university?

Comment: We have a number of lecturers in the math department at the University of Tennessee who have successfully been using flipped classrooms for a couple of years now.

Comment: Yes, Lorena Barba at BU has been very successful and you can find several articles by her or about her classroom on the web.

Comment: Lorena Barba, per @DavidKetcheson, is right on the money with great, extensively cited, very smart discussion. I've never personally participated as a student or otherwise, but its an interesting concept. Here's a great "update" article from here: http://lorenabarba.com/blog/everybodys-flippin-an-update-on-the-flipped-classroom/

Comment: @BrianDHall maybe you could summarize that post and turn it into an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Oxford and Cambridge University courses in England have always operated a bit like this.  In my Oxford Maths course, I'd attend 1 or 2 1-hour long lectures on the subject, have worksheets to do, then have classes in college of about 5 students to 1 instructor where we would discuss and work through the material.

What you're suggesting is basically the same, but having recorded lectures.  Given that most of the lectures were non-interactive, it amounts to much the same thing.  In general, I found it a very successful approach.